# Flutter App is restarting/crashing when launching app after minimizing it and using another app for a while

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrapped my `MaterialApp` with `WithForegroundTask` by using `flutter_foreground_task`.

I am uploading some files by using `Dio`. And I am displaying their progress on my UI.

So, whenever I am minimizing the app and opening it again, all state is saved, and progress is updated as expected and UI is also rendering as it should.

The problem is that on a specific phone, when I am minimizing and then opening again the app again, it works perfectly. But, when I am minimizing the app, opening some other app (like camera, and start recording a video and then closing it) and then opening my app again, it is restarting (I think due to crashing) and all progress is lost.

How can i prevent this. Like what might be the issue? I don't understand. The ram is pretty low on that device (2 gb) and processor is not that good, but still, the task that I am performing in my app is not so much heavy that it should crash.

Answer (score 1):

its normal in low devices, your app restart not because of crash, i think your app is closed by the system, to free some memory for the other applications, in this case you have to aware how could you restore your application state in case of force close by the system or any other case.
You could use one of these to save your application state:

- [Isar database](https://pub.dev/packages/isar)
- [Realm database](https://pub.dev/packages/realm)
- [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

and if you want to run code even if the app is closed, you can use one of these:

- [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)
- [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service)
- [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch)

Comment: Ok, but if the app is closed by the system, all my processes will stop. So, my uploading will be cancelled. How I might fix that?

Comment: @ShreyanshSharma look the edit